# Loop for all my dataframes

Tags: r

I wanna make a loop for the data frames
I can only do it for one dataframe, here's my code:

```
d <- list(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)

for (j in 1:length(d1) ) {
avg[j] = mean(d1[,j], na.rm=TRUE)
ecart[j]=sd(d1[,j], na.rm=TRUE)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `lapply` and avoid `for` loop for each side effect ( no need to pre-allocate before looping):

```
lapply(d,get_stats)    ## loops over list of data.frames
```

Where I define your function to something like this:

```
get_stats <- 
    function(d) 
     c(colMeans(d, na.rm=TRUE),   ## I vectorize your loop here
       sapply(d,sd,na.rm=TRUE))   ## avoid a for loop again here
```

Comment: Yes That's what I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should be looping through d not d1, no?

Maybe something like this:

```
for(j in 1:length(d)){ 
  avg = apply(d[[j]], 2, function(x) mean(x, na.rm=TRUE))
  ecart = apply(d[[j]], 2, function(x) sd(x, na.rm=TRUE))
}
```

Comment: Yes, I can do it for each data frame seperately! I want a loop for all the data frames, which give me the results by `print`

Comment: I just edited my response with a solution

Answer (score 0):

You can write your code in a function and call `lapply`

```
d <- list(d1,d2,d3,d4,d5)

f <- function (d) {
    for (j in 1:length(d1) ) 
    avg[j] = mean(d1[,j], na.rm=TRUE)
    ecart[j]=sd(d1[,j], na.rm=TRUE)
}

lapply(d, f)
```